# Import error while using pip install

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Program installs successfully using pip

```
sudo pip install -U rtfd-cli
```

but shows error while using it:

```
from helpers import formatstr'
'ImportError: No module named 'helpers'
```

It is working fine when installed using

```
sudo python install setup.py
```

Link to program: https://github.com/MUSoC/rtfd-cli/

Comment: Are you using any virtual env? As it is not possible to run this command -
 python install setup.py
 without `sudo` when not using any python virtual env.

Comment: Thank's for pointing out. Updated the command with sudo. I am not using any vietual env.

Answer (score 1):

You installed *rtfd* and not *helpers*. So python responds accordingly that there is no module named helpers.

The answer to your question is:

`>>> from rtfd.helpers import formatstr`

Never used rtfd, so how did I figure this out?

`>>> import rtfd`

Use the python built-in [help](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#help) function

`>>> help(rtfd) # now you see that helpers is an attribute`

Now do the same for rtfd.helpers

`>>> help(rtfd.helpers) # now you see formatstr function`

Comment: When I try "python3 rtfd.py" it shows error "ImportError: No module named 'rtfd.helpers'; 'rtfd' is not a package"

Comment: From the traceback, I believe the *helpers* import in *rtfd.py* is incorrect. Locate *rtfd.py* in the *\Lib\site-packages\rtfd* directory. Open it and change `from helpers import formatstr` to `from .helpers import formatstr` (this is an import from relative path). Save the file and try again.

Comment: SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Answer (score 0):

The actual import for that will be this:

```
from rtfd import helpers
#helpers.formatstr is the function you're looking for
```